# understanding implicity convertion in method in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion

```
internal T GetGameObject<T>(int gbId) where T : GameObject
    {
        return 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(BuildingGameObject) ? buildingGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(UnitGameObject) ? unitGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(MaterialGameObject) ? materialGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    null;
    }
```

I am having trouble understanding why I get the cs0029 error here (Cannot implicitly convert type ...BuildingGameObject to T) (Cannot implicitly convert type ...UnitGameObject to T) (Cannot implicitly convert type ...MaterialGameObject to T).

I have a similar method which does not produce an error.

```
internal V GetComponent<T, V>(int gbId, int componentId) where T : GameObject where V : BaseComponent, IBaseComponent
    {
        return  typeof(T) == typeof(BuildingGameObject) ? buildingGameObjects[gbId].GetComponentById<V>(componentId) : 
                typeof(T) == typeof(UnitGameObject) ? unitGameObjects[gbId].GetComponentById<V>(componentId) : 
                materialGameObjects[gbId].GetComponentById<V>(componentId);
    }
```

**Solution?**
I have found that if cast one of the return values (does not matter which one) and casting it to T makes the error disappears.

```
internal T GetGameObject<T>(int gbId) where T : GameObject
    {
        return (T)(
                    typeof(T) == typeof(BuildingGameObject) ? buildingGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(UnitGameObject) ? (GameObject)unitGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(MaterialGameObject) ? materialGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    null
                  );
    }
```

**Classes**

```
 internal class BuildingGameObject : GameObject {...}
 internal class UnitGameObject : GameObject {...}
 internal class MaterialGameObject : GameObject {...}
```

**Dictionaries**

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, UnitGameObject> unitGameObjects;
private readonly Dictionary<int, MaterialGameObject> materialGameObjects;
private readonly Dictionary<int, BuildingGameObject> buildingGameObjects;
```

To summarise I would really like to understand why the first code block does not work and what happens when I use the "Solution" I have found.

**Edit**

```
 internal T GetGameObject<T>(int gbId) where T : GameObject
    {
        return 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(BuildingGameObject) ? (T)buildingGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(UnitGameObject) ? (T)unitGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    typeof(T) == typeof(MaterialGameObject) ? (T)materialGameObjects[gbId] : 
                    null
                  ;
    }
```

This gives me cs0030 (Cannot convert type ...BuildingGameObject to T) (Cannot convert type ...UnitGameObjectto T) (Cannot convert type ...MaterialGameObjectto T) instead.

Comment: `GetGameObject` returns an object of type `T`. `T` is `GameObject` or a descendant (e.g. `BuildingGameObject`).  `unitGameObjects[x]` is of type `UnitGameObject`. You can't return a `UnitGameObject` when `T` is a `BuildingGameObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would note that your code is not "generic". Generic code works the same regardless of the input type - your code does three different things for three different input types, and a fourth thing (return `null`) for any others. The fact that the code is very similar for all types does *not* mean that it is generic.

You could just as easily have three different methods (`GetBuildingGameObject`, `GetUnitGameObject`, `GetMaterialGameObject`) and you wouldn't have these casting issues.

Or, have the same method with a return type of `GameObject` and let the *caller* cast to the appropriate type.

But, to answer the question...

The compiler does not know what type `T` is at compile time. You know (because you can read code) that `T` *has* to be `BuildingGameObject` for that operation to even execute, but the compiler is not programmed to do that level of static analysis and know that the object can be case from `BuildingGameObject` to whatever `T` is. If your core were written poorly, `T` could be a `UnitGameObject`, and there's no cast from `BuildingGameObject` to `UnitGameObject`, so it generates an error.

The second method works because `GetComponentById<V>` returns a `V` so it's returning the proper type.

You can "assure" the compiler that the object is of the right type by doing an *explicit* cast:

```
typeof(T) == typeof(BuildingGameObject) ? (T)buildingGameObjects[gbId]
```

In your solution, you are doing an *explicit* cast. tells the compiler "I am certain that the cast is valid at run-time, so treat it as if it is a valid cast". At run-time, if the cast is not allowed you'll get a run-time error.

Comment: Why not just use `as` instead of `typeof`?